# how to get json array from api

Tags: javascript, json

I can not get the title in JavaScript from my API. I want to display the title in HTML.

`api:(https://k0wa1un85b.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/production/books)`

JSON response looks like:

```
{"statusCode":200,"body":[{"id":"4f160b1f8693cdbeb96ac8be135ff0f9","title":"Harry Potter"}]}
```

javascript:

```
  <body>    
    <p>
        title: <span id="tit"></span><br/>
    </p>    
    <script>
        const api_url = 'https://k0wa1un85b.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/production/books';
        async function getISS() {
            const response = await fetch(api_url);
            const data = await response.json();

             console.log(data);

            const {title} = (data);

            document.getElementById('tit').textContent = title;
        }
        getISS();
    </script>
  </body
```

Comment: const {title} = data.body[0];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use it like this.

```js
const api_url = 'https://k0wa1un85b.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/production/books';
        async function getISS() {
            const response = await fetch(api_url);
            const data = await response.json();

             console.log(data);

            const title = data.body[0].title;
            console.log(title)
            document.getElementById('tit').textContent = title;
        }
 getISS();
```

```html
<p>
   title: <span id="tit"></span><br/>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use dot notation to get data from json

```
async function getISS() {
      const response = await fetch(api_url);
      const data = await response.json();

      console.log(data);

      const title = data[0].title;

      document.getElementById('tit').textContent = title;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by other answers, you can get the value using the array index like this:

```js
var response = {"statusCode":200,
"body":[{
"id":"4f160b1f8693cdbeb96ac8be135ff0f9",
"title":"Harry Potter"}]};
                
console.log(response.body[0].title);

var emptyResponse = {"statusCode":200,
"body":[]};
                
console.log(emptyResponse.body[0].title);
```

I just want to mention to include the null check otherwise it will through exception:

```js
var response = {"statusCode":200,
"body":[{
"id":"4f160b1f8693cdbeb96ac8be135ff0f9",
"title":"Harry Potter"}]};
                
if(response.body.length){console.log(response.body[0].title);}

var emptyResponse = {"statusCode":200,
"body":[]};
                
if(emptyResponse.body.length){console.log(emptyResponse.body[0].title);}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
const api_url = 'https://k0wa1un85b.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/production/books';
async function getISS() {
    const response = await fetch(api_url);
    const data = await response.json();
    const title = data.body[0]['title'];
    document.getElementById('tit').textContent = title;
}
getISS();
```

```html
<p>
    title: <span id="tit"></span><br/>
</p>
```